# MySQL join to two tables for different summaries

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join a `Clients` table to a `Timesheets` table twice, to get two summaries.

```
    select * from Clients;
    +-----------+-------+
    | Unique ID | Name  |
    +-----------+-------+
    |         1 | James |
    |         2 | Jill  |
    +-----------+-------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    select * from Timesheets;
    +-----------+-------+----------+
    | Client ID | Hours | Category |
    +-----------+-------+----------+
    |         1 |   1.5 | Onsite   |
    |         1 |   1.5 | Onsite   |
    |         1 |     1 | Remote   |
    |         2 |   1.5 | Remote   |
    +-----------+-------+----------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to join from Clients to Timesheets twice, once to get the total Onsite Hours, and once to get the Remote hours.

If I do them separately, they work fine.

E.G. This:

```
    SELECT Clients.`Unique ID`, Clients.Name, sum(onsite.`Hours`) as `Onsite Total Hours`
    FROM Clients
    LEFT JOIN Timesheets AS onsite
         ON Clients.`Unique ID`=onsite.`Client ID` AND onsite.Category='Onsite'
    GROUP BY Clients.`Unique ID`;
```

Returns:

```
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+
    | Unique ID | Name  | Onsite Total Hours |
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+
    |         1 | James |                  3 |
    |         2 | Jill  |               NULL |
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+
```

And this:

```
    SELECT Clients.`Unique ID`, Clients.Name, sum(remote.`Hours`) as `Remote Total Hours`
    FROM Clients
    LEFT JOIN Timesheets AS remote
         ON Clients.`Unique ID`=remote.`Client ID` AND remote.Category='Remote'
    GROUP BY Clients.`Unique ID`;
```

Returns:

```
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+
    | Unique ID | Name  | Remote Total Hours |
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+
    |         1 | James |                  1 |
    |         2 | Jill  |                1.5 |
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+
```

BUT, when I run this:

```
    SELECT Clients.`Unique ID`, Clients.Name, sum(onsite.`Hours`) as `Onsite Total Hours`, sum(remote.`Hours`) as `Remote Total Hours`
    FROM Clients
    LEFT JOIN Timesheets AS onsite
         ON Clients.`Unique ID`=onsite.`Client ID` AND onsite.Category='Onsite'
    LEFT JOIN Timesheets AS remote
         ON Clients.`Unique ID`=remote.`Client ID` AND remote.Category='Remote'
    GROUP BY Clients.`Unique ID`;

    +-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
    | Unique ID | Name  | Onsite Total Hours | Remote Total Hours |
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |         1 | James |                  3 |                  2 |
    |         2 | Jill  |               NULL |                1.5 |
    +-----------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

As you can see from above, the total shown for James Onsite is correct, but Remote isn't. The '1' has been counted twice...

Answer (score 1):

Try using case when then like:

```
SELECT c.uniqueId, c.name, SUM(CASE WHEN t.category='Onsite' THEN t.Hours ELSE 0 END) AS 'Onsite', SUM(CASE WHEN t.category='Remote' THEN t.Hours ELSE 0 END) AS 'Remote'
FROM clients c INNER JOIN Timesheets t ON c.uniqueId = t.clientId
GROUP BY c.uniqueId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.`UniqueID`, a.Name, sum(case when b.Category='Remote' then b.`Hours` end) as `Remote Total Hours`, sum(case when b.Category='Onsite' then b.`Hours` end) as `Onsite Total Hours`
    FROM Clients a, Timesheets b
    WHERE a.`UniqueID`=b.`ClientID` 
    GROUP BY a.`UniqueID`;
```

Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76217/1) where you can also do tests.